# KB5030211 breaks me running intellij from WSL2

Tags: windows-10, wsl2, intellij-idea

**update 2023 09 22:**
for now i want to keep my env working until i finished my project. In Oct. I will revisit this issue.

after de-install of KB5030211 it works again.

### My Setup

for an x-server i use vcxsrv or x410 and both dont work with the KB although i can open xclock.

### current Win/WSL2 installed:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19041  2311
```

Win10 is @ 19045.3324

note that i did not update WSL2 to the MS store version! I had tried this in april but this led to another problem that i wasnt able to solve:

> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-in-the-microsoft-store-is-now-generally-available-on-windows-10-and-11/comment-page-2/#comments
>
> - while the install works and I can open the bash in principle, I was unsuccessful in starting a tab from consoleZ
>
>   - uninstalling the app
>     version worked though and seemingly restored the previous behavior
> - the article states that 22h2 is a pre req but my win update didn’t want to install it -- even after removing the 21h2 constraint … so this
>   might be the cause for the above snag

---

PS: in the meantime i have 22H2 but had no need to try this out again

Comment: Your problem is directly connected to the fact you are not using the current supported version of WSL.

Comment: What error are you receiving when attempting to run IntelliJ?

Comment: @Ramhound is that definitive knowledge ? Would you care to expand how the KB is breaking my setup ? AFAICS the KB has no relation to WSL.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, updating to the current MS Store version of WSL was the solution (in the meantime).